# Writing to an s3 mounted directory

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, s3fs

hopefully someone can advise.

I've recently mounted an s3 bucket to a directory /s3 on my ubuntu amazon ec2 instance -following: http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon. This was set up in order to store a file directory of Drupal.

The plan was to adjust the owner and group settings of the directory to start uploading files etc:

```
>> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /s3
chown: changing ownership of `/s3': Input/output error
```

As you can see I can't change the details.  Am I missing something? Could this be due to a faulty set up..

```
>> sudo /usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other mybucket /s3/
```

Cheers!

Comment: u resolved this issue? Can you post how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the uid=xxx and gid=xxx options for fuse.  Specify the UID and GID of your www-data user, and it the mount point will be owned by that UID and GID.  I believe the command-line syntax is -o uid=xxx and so forth.

(Those are the options I specify in /etc/fstab when doing the same activity)